# Alerts for new uploads only, not moved documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert

I am using SharePoint in Office 365, and have visitors uploading documents into a document library. Once we have processed these, I then move them into another document folder inside the library (to show that they have been processed).

I have set up an instant alert for new document uploads to let me know when things are uploaded, however I am also getting instant alerts for when the are moved. In my head, when I move them they are "not new" and therefore I do not want an alert to tell me I have moved them.

Can anyone please advise, is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Are you using SharePoint OOTB Alerts??

Comment: Yes I am. Have never used alerts before, so is there a different way of doing them?

Comment: Yes, try following below steps to create new alert or modify existing alerts.

Comment: Those are the settings that I have, but I am getting alerts every time something is moved as well as uploaded.

Comment: You will get the alert only when new document is uploaded or created from library itself. Are you moving documents from same library to the folders (within same library) or moving documents from another library to this library?

Comment: I am moving them into a folder within the same library, a "completed" folder. I have tried deleting the alert and setting up a new one, but still having the same problem, that when they are moved, I get an alert to tell me that it has been added like it is a brand new document when it isn't.

Comment: Strange. I am doing the same. I am not getting the alert on moving document. I am getting alert only when I am uploading new document.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below Steps:

1. Go to SharePoint Library.
2. Click on the ellipsis(...) from document library ribbon.
3. Select **Alert me** if you want to create a new alert or **Manage my alerts** if you want to modify previously created alert.
4. If you have choose **Manage my alerts** then select the alert you want modify (In case of new alert ignore this step).
5. Select the **Change Type** options as given in below image.
6. Select **Save**.

[image]